# BGE: realtime random shape generator (python)

Tags: python, game-engine, objects

I want to set up a script that randomly changes the shape of an object.
What I have so far is:

```
from bge import logic
import random

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
object = cont.owner


for mesh in object.meshes:
   for m_index in range(len(mesh.materials)):
      for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(m_index)):

         vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, v_index)
         vertex.setXYZ([ random.random(), random.random(), random.random()])
```

This works pretty well. However, since every single vertex gets its own random location, the cube turns out something like this:

[image: random shape 1]

what I want is something like this:

[image: random shape 2]

My question is: how can I achieve something like that?

I think the "broken" shapes happen because 3 vertices are connected to each other and if they all get a different random position, the shape "breaks"?

I assume, that I have to give the vertices 1-3 the same random position, then the vertices 4-6 the same random position and so on?

If that is true, how could I write that down in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified the code as follows :

- added a dictionary that stores the vertex position and the generated offset by random.uniform()
- for each vertex check if there is already an offset for this position , if so we add this offset to the old position
- if there is no offset calculated for this position we generate a new one and store it in the dictionary, we also add it to the old position

this method gives the vertices that has the same position  the same offseet

---

```
from bge import logic
import random
from mathutils import Vector

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
object = cont.owner

for mesh in object.meshes:
   print(mesh)
   verts_shift = dict()
   for m_index in range(len(mesh.materials)):
      print(m_index)
      for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(m_index)):
         print(v_index)
         vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, v_index)
         xyz_old= vertex.getXYZ().freeze()
         xyz_shift = verts_shift.get(xyz_old, None) 
         if xyz_shift :
             vertex.setXYZ(xyz_old+xyz_shift)
         else :
             xyz_shift = Vector(( random.uniform(-0.5,0.5), random.uniform(-0.5,0.5), random.uniform(-0.5,0.5) ))
             verts_shift[xyz_old] = xyz_shift
             vertex.setXYZ(xyz_old+xyz_shift)           

         print(xyz_old, xyz_shift)
```

---

[image]

Comment: this is a very good solution, thank you! Only thing left is that the cube's size grows and grows... is there something one can do to prevent that from happening? Something like a limiter which says that it shouldnt get bigger than two times its size or something like that?

Comment: @Sputi the cube is not supposed to grow ( the random var is negative/positive   -0.5 to 0.5 ) so it grow and shrink randomly, also apply the scale because this is in the local coordinates, to prevent it from growing you can test  `xyz+offset > limit : generete new offset`

Comment: Well this makes sense. Still, the object grows eventualy ( put sensor freuq. to 0 and it happens very fast. Even though the random var is negative/positive -0.5 to 0.5 and scale is applyied. Very strange...

Comment: I will take a look later and update the answer

Comment: How does one know in which order the vertices are stored? For example if I only want to alter the top left corner of the cube (all three vertices at once)? Its not 0,1,2 but 23, 40, 48...?